# Is sensitivity * precision a useful statistic?

Tags: machine-learning, descriptive-statistics

I'm working on a binary classification problem and I'm trying to assess the performance of my model to correctly classify the positive class (hopefully getting a probability). I'm using the positive predictive value (PPV) statistic. The issue with the PPV is that I can move the classification threshold to the far right (on the score axis) and get a very high PPV, but also a very high miss ratio (low sensitivity). However, if I form the product of ***PPV * sensitivit***y then I can search for the classification threshold that maximizes that product. This product seems to be an excellent statistic on the performance of the model on the positive class but I can't find any reference on it.  I need something that I and others can interpret. In my opinion, ***sensitivity * precision*** is saying something like (say in the field of cancer detection) "the fraction of positive diagnosis detected that are truly positive." Technically, the probability of a positive diagnosis given it was detected, given it was diagnosed positive by the model. I've generated a bunch of fake datasets and confusion matrices, and adjusted the classification threshold around and this ***sensitivity * precision*** can explain how well the model is doing on the positive class. So my questions are:

- Does ***PPV * sensitivity*** make any sense as a statistic?
- If this product makes sense, what is it saying about the model's performance? Does it have a name?
- Is it a probability (PPV is a probability while sensitivity seems to be a ratio)?

Thanks.

Comment: Threshold-based metrics are generally discouraged. Why do you not use the log loss or Brier score to evaluate the probability outputs of your model?

Comment: I guess because I want to know what are the model's chances of truly detecting the positive class; not to know its performance overall.

Comment: Have you read Frank Harrell's blog posts ([1](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/) [2](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/)) about classification vs probability estimation? That you're concerned about tradeoffs between false positives and false negatives tells me that you regard those errors differently.

Comment: The model will not *truly detect the positive class*. All it will do is to give you a *predicted probability* for an instance of being in the positive class. You can assess whether these predicted probabilities are well-calibrated using [proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info). In addition (and this is a *separate* topic), you can take *decisions* and assess the costs of wrong decisions. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352).

Comment: Further to your point, as Dave notes, sensitivity *and* precision are highly controversial. I would go so far to call them useless, and worse, actively misleading. See [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) Every criticism against accuracy at that thread applies equally to sensitivity and precision. A fortiori, the product of two useless and misleading measurements will also be useless to misleading.